# how does the instantiate method in unity3d works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Unity scripts has the ability to instantiate other script components or GameObject's via a the Instantiate method (which isn't a generic method).
I just wonder what it does under the hood, if it uses reflection won't it lead to bad performance if we call it multiple times ?

Link to the Unity reference : [Object Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Comment: I wouldn't say bad performance, but it is not fast. For example it's better to use object pools instead of instantiating and destroying game objects.